# Switching from netbook edition to desktop-edition

Tags: kubuntu, kubuntu-netbook

So I've get the official Kubuntu 12.04 CD. I've installed it on a netbook. It have installed a netbook edition (without asking me...). So that I see

[image]

while I would really prefer the standard plasma:

[image]

I seem to have `kubuntu-desktop` package installed. How do I switch the plasma to the desktop one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Open system settings

[image]

- In system settings click on "Workspace Behavior"

[image]

- In Workspace Settings click on "Workspace" in sidebar. Select your Workspace type from drop down menu and click save to apply changes.

[image]

Now just wait for the magic to happen!

Comment: after that procedure the window buttons (close, minimize, maximize) are messed up. This is frustrating.